# Zebra Symbol LI4278 - Remove leading character

Tags: barcode-scanner

Not sure if Stack is the right place to ask this, but I am trying to find out how to remove "T" prefix characters from the barcode by programming the reader.

[Link to Reference Material](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra_new_ia/en-us/manuals/barcode-scanners/li4278-prg-en.pdf)

I have struggled to find anything like this in the user manuals, but that could just be my bad reading of them! The closest thing I could find is an FN1 character substitution option, and I'm not sure if that's what I'm after.

Edit: Note that the T is an actual part of the barcode; it is the first character and I want it removed every time I scan a barcode.

Comment: How did the 'T' prefix get added?  I would expect scanning the first barcode on page 5-20 to remove any prefixes, unless there is something else in place adding the prefix such as ADF

Comment: The default settings of the device do not seem to add anything, so why not try resetting with `Set Factory Defaults` on page 108, chapter 5-4 of the manual?

Comment: added detail: it's part of the barcode, not an additional prefix character, but simply a character at the start of the barcode

Comment: why does this need to be done on the scanner side rather than on the consumption side of the data?

Comment: Often we are using the scanner to input barcodes into notepad, Excel, all over the place as raw text without an intermediary.